# HTTP requests refresh the browser after migrating to Angular 4

Tags: angular

Since I migrated some apps from Angular 2 to 4, I noticed an annoying behavior. Every HTTP request done via user action, causes a browser refresh. The code below reproduces the error.

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService() {

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    toggleFav(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
        let data = { "fav": !product.fav };
        this._http
            .patch(`api/products/${product.id}`, data)
            .map((r: Response) => r.json() as Product);
    }
}
```

The component:

```
@Component({...})
export class ProductComponent {

    product: Product;

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService) { }

    fav(): void {
        this._productService
            .toggleFav(product)
            .subscribe((updatedProduct: Product) => {
                this.product = updatedProduct;
            });
    }
}
```

The template:

```
<div>
    ...
    <button type="button" (click)="fav()">
        <i [ngClass]="{ 'fav-on': product.fav, 'fav-off': !product.fav }"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

In Angular 2, this code runs as expected: the HTTP client requests the server and once the Observable notifies the updated data, it is bound to the template, forcing the Change Detection to occur. But the same code running over Angular 4, causes the browser to refresh the whole app.

I don't know who is the responsible of this behavior. Maybe the HTTP client, maybe the library Zone.js, maybe me, etc. Have someone got this behavior too? Any way to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using the `angular-cli` and are you connecting to a local webserver?

Comment: Yes I do, both of them. The version of Angular CLI is 1.0.3, and the server I'm using as API is a local [JSON Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). Can any of them be involved on the issue commented?

Answer (score 5):

Because angular-cli has live-reload, which means if changes occur in files (doesn't necessarily need to be project files), it will trigger a reload. My guess is when you do the `PATCH` request this either modifies file under watch in the angular-cli or it's logging in the JSON server which triggers the reload from the angular-cli.

A possible solution could be to move your JSON server files to a different location, or turn off live-reload for the cli using the `-lr` option:

```
ng serve -lr=false
```

This of course speaks for itself, but let me just put it out there, because you said you migrated some apps to angular4. Are you deploying those apps with `ng serve`? Or are you only experiencing those problems during development. Because for deployment you should use the `ng build {options}` command

Comment: You are totally right with your approach. The `db.json` file, corresponding the API exposed by JSON Server, was inside the watched directory, so any edition on this file was reloading the browser. My fault, embarrassing moment here T.T

The Angular 2 apps were developed by hand, no tools were used. In our way to move to Angular 4 we decided to use the CLI to ease the scaffolding tasks, but I did not think on it as the origin of the problem -concretely the Live Reload option-.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You just saved my day. This seems so obvious, yet when debugging I never thought of it...